# Why decrypt returns null after storing encrypted text, iv and key in database

Tags: php

I have a problem decrypting my cipher text  in PHP after I retrieve from database (MySQL). I store the IV and the key as well.
But when I encrypt and decrypt immediately, it works correctly, but the problem occurs when I try to decrypt after I have stored and retrieve from the database.
Key and plain text are obtained from post data

```
$cipher="aes-128-gcm";  
//Encrypt
$tag="";
$ivlen=openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv= openssl_random_pseudo_bites($ivlen);
$ciphertext=openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $tag); 
//Decrypt
$ciphertext=openssl_encrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $tag);
//Decrypt after Database retrieval
    $cyphertext=$row['pass']; 
    $iv=$row['iv'];
    $key=$row['c_no'];
$ciphertext=openssl_encrypt($ciphertext, 
    $cipher, $key, $options=0, $tag);
```

Comment: If you're storing raw, unencoded ciphertext in CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT columns you're going to have a bad time. Use BIN/VARBIN/BLOB.

Comment: The cipher returns as base64 by default. And that's what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Now that I try running it, your code is riddled with errors.

- `openssl_random_pseudo_bites()` is not a function.
- `openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $tag)` is missing the IV entirely, and `$options=0` doesn't make sense at all. Just use `0`.
- Your 'Decrypt' sections still call `openssl_encrypt()`.

Here is a *working* encrypt:

```
$cipher="aes-128-gcm";

//Encrypt
$tag="";
$key = 'asdasdasda';
$plaintext = 'asdasdsdasdasdasda';
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext=openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);

var_dump($ivlen, $iv, $ciphertext, $tag);
```

And bear in mind that while the ciphertext appears to be returned base64-encoded, the IV and tag are not. You'll either need to base64 those yourself, or use binary column types.

Also, turn `error_reporting` on/up so that you actually *see* these errors and can address them.

Comment: I don't seem to understand you. Sorry for typing mistake in the code I provided. But works fine. My problem is decrypt from Database. When I decrypt without storing in data base, it works fine except when I retrieve info from Database. Please read my description above

Comment: I have even changed my $iv to $iv=md5($ivlen) but still not working after storing in database